# is creating dummy variable mandatory for calculating propensity score either in logistic regression or cox regression modeling?

Tags: sas

Shall we create dummy variables to calculate propensity score using either approach of logistic or Cox regressions modeling?

Could any one shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by create dummy variables. Both PROC LOGISTIC and PHREG support CLASS statements that will create the dummy variables by default. Have you reviewed any of the examples of each of these procedures that deal with categorical variables?  https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=15.1&docsetTarget=statug_phreg_examples03.htm&locale=en

Comment: And the example for Logistic regression is here https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=15.1&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_examples02.htm&locale=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. First you would need a categorical variable, not a continuous variable. If you have continuous variables they you have no need for dummy variables. If you have categorical variables you need dummy variables, however, SAS will create the dummy variables for you via the CLASS statement. Each of the procedures, Logistic or Cox regression procs, have examples that illustrate how to deal with categorical variables.

Logistic Regression
https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=15.1&docsetTarget=statug_phreg_examples03.htm&locale=en

PHREG/COX Regression
https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=15.1&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_examples02.htm&locale=en

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in what a propensity score is, right.

For example, in propensity score matching you are matching people with similar propensity score (probability of being in the exposure group).

The end result is a probability, so the type of variables that lead to the beta coefficients doesn't matter, unless you are interested in looking at the dichotomous versions of the variables and they are important.

I personally create dummy because when I look at absolute standardized differences between the pre and post matching process the mathematics are easier IMHO.